# My dropdown menu flashes for a second and then dissapears, or doesn't react at all when clicking the button

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I have two categories, Women and Men, when clicking on each of them a menu with categories drops down, for Women it works fine, for Men though when I click, it appears and lasts for a second and then dissapears. preventDefault() doesn't seem to work. In HTML I used same div classes for both Women and Men, can this rise an issue with its functionality? Thanks

HTML

```
<div class="man">
                            <a href="" id="man-shoes">Men</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-gender">
                                <div class="drop-content">
                                        <div class="drop-columns">
                                            <div class="main-element">
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Shop by Sport</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Running</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Walking</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Lifestyle</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="drop-columns">
                                            <div class="main-element">
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Shop by Brand</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Nike</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Adidas</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Puma</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Vans</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Reebok</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Sketchers</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="drop-columns column3">
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <img src="" alt="">
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">New Arrivals</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <img src="" alt="">
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Sales</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-gender {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 90px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.drop-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 150px;
  color: black;
  width: 80%;
}
```

JS

```
const dropdownGender = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-gender");
const womanBtn = document.getElementById("woman-shoes")
const manBtn = document.getElementById("man-shoes")

Array.from(dropdownGender).forEach(element => {


womanBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (element.style.display === "none") {
    element.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
})

manBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (element.style.display === "none") {
        element.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
})

element.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
    e.target.style.display = "none";
    e.preventDefault();
})
})
```

Comment: I would only hide it when the user click again, in term of ux, i think it's better to have mouseenter/mouseleave or click/click (toggle), but mixing both is confusing for the user. It's easy to leave the dropdown-gender element with the mouse, i would use the man element instead for the mouseleave, which would include the button

Comment: Also adding padding will prevent the user from accidentally leaving your element, if the text of your dropdown is too close to the edge of your element, it will be harder to use your dropdown, because the mouse will easily leave the element.

Answer (score 0):

With JS

```js
const dropdownGender = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-gender");
const mainContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("man");
const womanBtn = document.getElementById("woman-shoes")
const manBtn = document.getElementById("man-shoes")




manBtn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    dropdownGender[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
    dropdownGender[0].style.opacity = 1;
})
mainContainer[0].addEventListener('mouseleave',(e)=>{
    dropdownGender[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    dropdownGender[0].style.opacity = 0;
})
```

```css
.man{
  position : relative;
  background-color: orange;
  
}
.dropdown-gender{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  visibility : hidden;
  opacity : 0;
}


.drop-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 150px;
  color: black;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="man">
    <a href="#" id="man-shoes">Men</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-gender">
                                <div class="drop-content">
                                        <div class="drop-columns">
                                            <div class="main-element">
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Shop by Sport</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Running</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Walking</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Lifestyle</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="drop-columns">
                                            <div class="main-element">
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Shop by Brand</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Nike</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Adidas</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Puma</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Vans</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Reebok</a>
                                            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Sketchers</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="drop-columns column3">
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <img src="" alt="">
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">New Arrivals</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <img src="" alt="">
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Sales</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
</div>
```

Without JS

```css
.man{
  position : relative;
  background-color: orange;
  
}
.dropdown-gender{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  visibility : hidden;
  opacity : 0;
}

.man:hover .dropdown-gender{
  visibility : visible;
  opacity : 1;
}

.drop-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 150px;
  color: black;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="man">
        <a href="#" id="man-shoes">Men</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-gender">
                                    <div class="drop-content">
                                            <div class="drop-columns">
                                                <div class="main-element">
                                                    <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Shop by Sport</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Running</a>
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Walking</a>
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Lifestyle</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="drop-columns">
                                                <div class="main-element">
                                                    <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Shop by Brand</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Nike</a>
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Adidas</a>
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Puma</a>
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Vans</a>
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Reebok</a>
                                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Sketchers</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="drop-columns column3">
                                                <div class="column">
                                                    <img src="" alt="">
                                                    <a href="" class="dropdown-item">New Arrivals</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="column">
                                                    <img src="" alt="">
                                                    <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Sales</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    </div>
```